# Display an svg image on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I encounter a problem when I want to display an SVG image with the library D3.js on Google Chrome.

Below is the code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("embed");

svg.attr("src","img/drawing.svg").attr("type","image/svg+xml");
```

This code works on Firefox, but not on Google Chrome (same problem if I use object instead of embed).

But if I add this style to my SVG picture : `attr("style", "display:block")`, my picture displays on Google Chrome.

...Can someone explain me what happens? Because it's pretty ugly to display my image like that.

Comment: [This blog post](http://henkelmann.eu/2010/12/16/display_svg_image_same_size_in_decent_browsers) might help.

Answer (score 2):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp), the embed tag is "*deprecated in HTML4 and XHTML (but allowed in HTML5)*". You should use the object tag. The following snippet works in my Chrome:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("object");

svg.attr("data", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg")
   .attr("type","image/svg+xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, but my doctype was in HTML5 ... Anyway it's a weird behaviour.